# Decidable theories of arithmetic with nontrivial arithmetic hierarchies

Tags: logic, reference-request, computational-complexity, model-theory, computability

This seems like a question I should know the answer to, but I don't; and I can't find an answer online.

Usually the way we prove that a theory of arithmetic (Presburger, Skolem, . . .) is decidable is via *quantifier elimination*. I'm curious about whether there are examples of (reasonably natural) theories of arithmetic which are decidable, but not even model complete (ideally, whose quantifier hierarchy *never* collapses).

*Context: I've shown that a certain second-order theory, built off a first-order subtheory $T$ of $PA$, is non-set-theoretically absolute in a specific way. But currently, the only way I know how to do this is via an undecidable $T$. Since decidability isn't actually part of the problem I'm approaching, it seems like I should be able to make do with a decidable $T$; but the obstacle I'm running into is that I need $\mathbb{N}$ (as a model of this theory) to have a definable, non-existentially-definable subset.*

I've used the complexity theory tag, even though this isn't directly a complexity-theoretic question, since I suspect an affirmative answer will be related to some complexity-theoretic concerns.

Comment: I might be missing something entirely or this might be exactly what you are **not** looking for, but if we replace $+$ in Presburger arithmetic with a trinary relation symbol ($\gamma(x,y,z)$ which holds iff $x + y = z$) should remain decidable and should not be model complete. However, If you are asking for extensions of $(\mathbb{N}; +)$, I have bupkis.

Comment: @KyleGannon: And I have learnt a new word!